# I want to modify all elements with the same query

Tags: javascript

**I want to modify all elements that use the same query via a function. (The function is not changed.)**

r is read, w is write, and a is write appended to existing content. When using this as get(query).r , .w , .a , I want to make all elements corresponding.

For example, if the class of 3 p tags is html, if you write get(".html").w("hello") in js, all tags with the class of 3 html should be changed to 'hello'.

```js
function get(id){
   if (id) {
      if (window === this) {
         return new get(id);
      }
      var query = document.querySelectorAll(id)
      for(var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
         this.e = query[i];
         return this;
      }
   } else {
      return "getError : The attribute and value of a tag such as id or class specified by get does not exist. ";
   }
  }
get.prototype = {
   r: function () {
      return this.e.innerText;
   },
   w: function (writing) {
      return this.e.innerText = writing;
   },
   a: function (writing) {
      return this.e.innerText = this.e.innerText += writing;
   }
};
```

```html
<a href="#" class="test">js</a>
<p href="#" class="test">html</p>
<a href="#" class="test">test</a>
<script>
   get(".test").w("hello")
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this line

```
for(var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
  this.e = query[i];
  return this;
}
```

You are only returning the first element. Thus, it only changes the inner text of the first element.

It seems that you are trying to assign a prototype to HTML elements, which is not recommended, so I modified your code.

I changed it so that the get function will return the whole HTMLCollection instead. Then I used the prototype of the get function to loop through the collection and set the text of the HTML elements.

```html
<a href="#" class="test">js</a>
<p href="#" class="test">html</p>
<a href="#" class="test">test</a>
<script>
  function get(id){
   if (id) {
      if (window === this) {
         return new get(id);
      }
      var query = document.querySelectorAll(id)
      return query
   } else {
      return "getError : The attribute and value of a tag such as id or class specified by get does not exist. ";
   }
  }
get.prototype = {
   r: function () {
      return this.e.innerText;
   },
   w: function (elems, writing) {
      return elems.forEach(x => x.innerText = writing);
   },
   a: function (writing) {
      return this.e.innerText = this.e.innerText += writing;
   }
};
   var elems = get(".test")
   get.prototype.w(elems, "html")
</script>
```

Comment: So how do I apply it to all elements with that class?

Comment: If the answer helped you, please accept the answer by clicking the gray checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a newer ES2015 class method, that uses static methods. Static methods are called directly on the class, without creating an instance/object of the class. That way, you can call the static method and pass the class object back into those methods.

More info here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static
- https://www.w3schools.com/JsrEF/jsref_class_static.asp

See snippet below:

```js
`use strict`

class Get {
  constructor(selector) {
    if (selector) return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    return [];
  }
  static Read(elements) {
    return elements.map(e => e.innerText)
  };
  static Write(elements, string) {
    elements.forEach(e => e.innerText = string)
  };
  static Append(elements, string) {
    elements.forEach(e => e.innerText = `${e.innerText}${string}`)
  };
}

console.log(Get.Read(new Get(`.test`)));

Get.Append(new Get(`.test`), `: Appended Text`);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="test">js</a>
<p href="#" class="test">html</p>
<a href="#" class="test">test</a>
```